# I know how to build HTML5/PHP pages on LAMP stack, not sure how to begin in Windows IIS land

Tags: php, html, iis, windows-server-2008, lamp

I need to build a reporting system that would pull the data from a Microsoft SQL server database.

I have done similar stuff with LAMP stack. But I'm wondering what's the best way to do so in a windows server world *(even if that means using PHP with IIS)* ? What tools are needed ? I have access to Visual studio, expression studio and any other Microsoft software.

EDIT: Should have clarified, that this system is going to be used internally. So need a robust solution that will work in production.

Comment: if you have simply googled for LAMP in Windows, you probably have already found out about WAMP.

Comment: For a little clarification: You can run Apache, MySQL, and PHP on windows. WAMP is a simple-to-use installer for the three.

Comment: The details are in the configuration. The system is only as robust as you make it. The component parts of your LAMP stack all run on windows (ok, apart from the L...), since you claim to know what you're doing with the AMP, why not just download the component parts and glue them together?

Comment: @Leigh He says IIS.. so at best it's WIMP. I voted to close because there is no specific question here.

Comment: @MikeB: I took "*even if that means IIS*" to mean he still had options. If he's stuck with IIS then... well... good luck :D

Comment: @Leigh - PHP on Windows 2008 is a first class citizen and works just as well as PHP on apache/linux, so there's not much luck needed unlike the old days :)

Comment: @Kev - Thank you, that helps me make my decision somewhat better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), however *be ware!* that both of these development packages *are for development only* and has some *serious security issues* if used it for production servers without prior configuration.

Comment: Should have clarified, that this system is going to be used internally. So need a robust solution that will work in production.

Comment: in that case I suggest you to talk with a Server Administrator to setup a secure server for you, or you can just google for tutorials and good luck.